# A script to test existence of primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Trying to figure out a SQL script to test the existence of primary keys in cerain tables.  If the table has no primary key, then the script should output the table name.

```
Tables to test:
TableA
TableB
TableC
```

After running the script (and lets say TableA and TableC have PKs, but not TableB), then the output would be below:

```
NoKeys
TableB
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
;WITH tables_with_pk AS (
  SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name  
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
      ON t.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME AND t.table_schema = tc.table_schema
  WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
)
SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
EXCEPT
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM tables_with_pk
```

Answer (score 16):

Returns 0 if no primary key,
Returns 1 if there is a primary key

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable'),'TableHasPrimaryKey')
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: This is very nice and much more compact that the typical approach of selecting from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score 13):

I don't have the exact/complete code for you, but here's the idea:

You'll need to loop through your list of tables in the database:

```
SELECT *  
FROM information_schema.tables
```

The code to check if a Primary Key exists for your table would be something like:

```
SELECT *  
FROM information_schema.table_constraints  
WHERE constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'   
AND table_name = @Your_Table_Name
```

Comment: So `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TableA','TableB','TableC') EXCEPT SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'`?

Comment: how do i alter it to just search the whole database?

Comment: nm just remove the where with the in clause

Answer (score 2):

My version:

```sql
SELECT 1  
FROM SYS.KEY_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE [TYPE] = 'PK' AND [PARENT_OBJECT_ID] = OBJECT_ID('USER.USER');
```

As a reference check Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Using%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio,-To%20delete%20a&text=In%20Object%20Explorer%2C%20expand%20the,is%20specified%20and%20click%20OK.).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' FROM 'TABLES' LEFT JOIN 'TABLE_CONSTRAINTS' USING('TABLE_SCHEMA', 'TABLE_NAME') WHERE 'TABLE_SCHEMA' = '__PUT_YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE__' AND 'CONSTRAINT_NAME' LIKE '%PRIMARY%' AND ISNULL('CONSTRAINT_CATALOG')
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Sean's answer and it worked for me. You can add the clause

`WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`

just before the `EXCEPT` statement if you don't want to also get views back.

```
;WITH tables_with_pk AS (
  SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
      ON t.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME AND t.table_schema = tc.table_schema
  WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
)
SELECT t.table_schema, t.table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
EXCEPT
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM tables_with_pk
```